# Why is my JSON invalid when making post request? (Postgres, Knex)

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, knex.js

I've been playing around with this for a while, and I have to say I'm rather stumped.

I have a table called "physical_sites", and created the column "history" as a "json" type in this table.

My API request function is as follows:

```
  const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + "physical_sites", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ data: jobSite }),
});
```

With my incoming data as:

```
{
    "physical_site_name": "Here",
    "physical_site_loc": "test",
    "created_by": "ME",
    "status": "Active",
    "history": [{
        "action_date": "2022-07-21T01:22:44.056Z",
        "action_taken": "Create Job Site",
        "action_by": "me",
        "action_by_id": 24,
        "action_comment": "Initial Upload",
        "action_key": "1jt9JPRLy7RHJUwmz3kqoy98u"
    }]
}
```

I will continually be adding items to the 'array' in history, so there will be multiple objects here. I checked this in an online JSON validator, and it seems correct.

Lastly, my "create" function in the controller is as follows:

```
  async function create(req, res) {
  const result = req.body.data;
  console.log(result);
  const data = await knex("physical_sites")
    .insert(result)
    .returning("*")
    .then((results) => results[0]); //insert body data into assets
  res.status(201).json({ data });
}
```

Fairly simple.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
    message: 'insert into "physical_sites" ("created_by", "history", "physical_site_loc", "physical_site_name", "status") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning 
* - invalid input syntax for type json'
```

Not exactly sure what is going on, can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(result);` is that outputting an object or a string? (use typeof if you're not sure) - I suspect `result` is a regular Javascript object, which isn't JSON, of course

Comment: "this is outputting an object" ... what is "this" that's doing "that"? you mean the console.log shows an Object? well, there's your issue, an Object is not JSON - which is why you get the error that says `invalid input syntax for type json` ... you need to send JSON if you want to store JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX the console.log is saying the 'typeof result' is an object.  am I not using JSON.stringify properly?

Comment: `am I not using JSON.stringify` - correct, you are NOT using JSON.stringify at all on the server ... you send JSON correctly, but your backend is probably saying "hey, this is JSON, I have middleware that handles JSON and parses it for me" - so your body ends up being an object - clearly, since `body.data` would not exists if `body` was still JSON .... to be clear: *body: JSON.stringify({ data: jobSite }),* is correct - but you're server code is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely one of you column for this table has a JSON type. I believe that it is the `history` column.

You could parse the history property to String before sending the request.

```js
// ...
body: JSON.stringify({ 
  data: { 
    ...jobSite,
    history: JSON.parse(jobSite.history) 
  }
}),
// ...
```